# How do I increase the arrow length on the pie chart in Charts.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

You look at this chart, the labels go into the graph. I want the labels outside the graph. I used [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) (I used pie chart)

[image]

Below is my code.

```js
var PIECHARTEXMPLE = $('#visitPieChart');
var pieChartExample = new Chart(PIECHARTEXMPLE, {
  type: 'pie',

  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontSize: 16
      }
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 40,
    responsive: true,

    pieceLabel: {
      mode: "label",
      position: 'outside',
      render: function(args) {
        var label = args.label,
          value = args.value,
          percentage = args.percentage;

        var hi = '\n';
        var test = 'hello';
        var result;
        result = hi + label + hi + test;

        return result;
      },
      fontColor: 'rgb(120,120,120)',
      fontSize: 18,
      segment: true,
      //arc: false
    },

    plugins: {
      labels: {
        render: 'percentage',
        fontColor: 'white',
        fontSize: '18',
        precision: 1,
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    //labels: Top4DocName,
    labels: ['test1test1test1test1', 'test2test2test2tset2', 'test3test3test3test3', "test4test4test4test4", 'test5test5test5test5'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "test",
      data: Top4DocNum,
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: arrBgColors,
      //borderColor: "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)",
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the PieceLabel Plugin .

You should add : arc: true, in order for the labels to be drawn in an arc i.e. the plugin documentation states :

```
 // draw label in arc, default is false
 // bar chart ignores this
 arc: true,
```